# Unable to build and add platform in Browser Ionic Cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I am trying to run the command

```
ionic cordova platform add browser
```

this is the error message that shows

[image]

I already have successfully executed the codes

```
npm install
npm install ionic -g
npm install cordova -g
```

I am not sure if the tags I included here are appropriate but kindly edit it if it's misleading. What can we do as a troubleshooting step for me to be able to run `ionic cordova platform add browser`?

**EDIT:**

For additional troubleshooting done, tried:

```
ionic cordova platform remove browser
ionic cordova platform add browser
```

Removing the `ionic` keyword is not accepted by the terminal

Comment: please check this.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48397839/cordova-cli-windows-enoent-error-when-executing-cordova-platform-add-android

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to remove the browser and add it back, make sure your root folder on your project than

1- `ionic cordova platform rm browser`

2- `ionic cordova platform add browser`

Hope it helps